# How do I route from another component in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What I want to achieve..

Able to route in two different navbars

route components here

when you login

route dashboard components here

More explanation

I have a landing page component

```
<navbar/>
  about page, contact, features and pricing are been routed here
<Router>
  <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/pricing" component={Pricing}/>
   <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
   <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
 <Switch/>
</Router>
<footer/>
```

now when you're logged in

there's a new navbar and sidebar for the dashboard

all other dashboard components should be routed here

```
<Router>
 <Navbar />
 <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/dashboard/edit" component={Edit} />
   <Route exact path="/dashboard/invite" component={Invite} />
   <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
 <Switch>
 <Sidebar />
<Router>
```

current solution is to repeat the sidebar and navbar components on every dashboard components then declare them as route path in the router wrapper

I do not want to repeat the sidebar and navbar on every dashboard component

Please let me know if there's any better way to achieve this

Comment: You didn't didn't include the code for Sidebar or Navbar. I don't understand what you are asking, by the looks of your code you just have these components once in a top-level component. You wouldn't need to put then anywhere else and they will be rendered anywhere thst top level component is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a top level Dashboard component and a top level home component that are routed without the 'exact' keyword. so your App.js looks like this:

```
<>
  <Router >
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={TopLevelDashboard} />
      <Route path="/" component={TopLevelHome} />
    </Switch>
  </Router >
</>
```

then put the subcomponents of Dashboard inside TopLevelDashboard.js like this:

```
<>
  <Navbar />  {/* the navbar in Dashboard components */}
  <Switch >
    <Route exact path="/dashboard/edit" component={Edit} />
    <Route exact path="/dashboard/invite" component={Invite} />
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
  </Switch >
</>
```

and similarly the Top level home component looks like this:

```
<>
  <navbar /> {/* the navbar in Home components */}
  <Switch >
    <Route exact path="/pricing" component={Pricing}/>
    <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
  </Switch >
  <footer />
</>
```

Comment: this worked perfectly for me...I knew there should be some implementation like this...but it was actually the "exact" that I was missing....Kudos to you Bagheri

Answer (score 0):

**You should put your code into a high-level component like `App.js` and add logic to hide one navbar when the user is not logged in.**

In components where you don't want your navbars to be shown, like the Login page you can hide it by leveraging `useLocation` hook to get the current pathName and compare it with the pathName in question.